# how to change the background color with change of tab

Tags: html, css

i have 3 tabs and wish that when  tab is selected its background color changes. something like this

[image]

At present the working code that i have is

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <ul id="myTab" class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified">
            <li class="active"><a href="#service-one" data-toggle="tab"><i class="fa fa-tree"></i> Service One</a>
            </li>
            <li class=""><a href="#service-two" data-toggle="tab"><i class="fa fa-car"></i> Service Two</a>
            </li>
            <li class=""><a href="#service-three" data-toggle="tab"><i class="fa fa-support"></i> Service Three</a>
            </li>
        </ul>

        <div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane fade active in" id="service-one">
                <h4>Service One</h4>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</p>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="service-two">
                <h4>Service Two</h4>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</p>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="service-three">
                <h4>Service Three</h4>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</p>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

But i don't want any background color for the selected tab content, only the color of tab should get chanaged. would appreciate any help

Comment: Have you written any CSS code for this yet?

Comment: @Rahul Desai i have taken reference from few question posted in stackoverflow itself, but they didn't worked for me.

Comment: it looks like you are using boostrap is that right?

Comment: @Tambo yes i am using bootstrap

Comment: @Sam Please post your non-working CSS code and the changes you made to it and we will take it from there. We would like to see the efforts that you have taken to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#myTab li.active a{background:blue;color:white;}
```

Try this if i get you.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well since you are using boostrap i think the active class is `active`

add this to your css

```
#myTab .active{background: blue}
```

Have a look at this [navbar](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar/)

[image]